# Texture mapping a circle made using GL_POLYGON

Tags: opengl

I am trying to map a texture to a circle using `GL_POLYGON` using this code:

```
void drawCircleOutline(Circle c, int textureindex)
{
    float angle, radian, x, y;       // values needed by drawCircleOutline

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureLib[textureindex]);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    for (angle=0.0; angle<360.0; angle+=2.0)
    {
        radian = angle * (pi/180.0f);

        x = (float)cos(radian) * c.r  + c.pos.x;
        y = (float)sin(radian) * c.r  + c.pos.y;

        glTexCoord2f(x, y);
        glVertex2f(x, y);
    }

    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

it looks like this when running.

[image: img1]

And should look like this:

[image: img2]

Comment: x and y you are passing into glTexCoord2f are being scaled by c.r and translated by c.pos, is this intended? Typical values in glTexCoord2f  are 0.0->1.0 (although it can wrap, I'm making sure you meant to have potentially large values).

Comment: Just a suggestion: Instead of GL_POLYGON I'd use a GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, , the starting vertex being at (0,0) and texture coordinate (0.5, 0.5) – this will give you a (slightly) robuster texture perspective correction. Plus it's not deprecated. Also I suggest switching to vertex arrays.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
radian = angle * (pi/180.0f);

xcos = (float)cos(radian);
ysin = (float)sin(radian);
x = xcos * c.r  + c.pos.x;
y = ysin * c.r  + c.pos.y;
tx = xcos * 0.5 + 0.5;
ty = ysin * 0.5 + 0.5;

glTexCoord2f(tx, ty);
glVertex2f(x, y);
```

Comment: Thank you soo much! :) would never of thought to do that the math slightly caught me out.