# Texture Mapping a square image onto a circle OpenGl

Tags: opengl, texture-mapping

I am trying to map a square image of a clock face onto a circle GL_POLYGON that I have created. I am currently using the following code:

```
        float angle, radian, x, y, xcos, ysin, tx, ty;       

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, an_face_texture1);

        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

        for (angle=0.0; angle<360.0; angle+=2.0)
        {
            radian = angle * (pi/180.0f);

            xcos = (float)cos(radian);
            ysin = (float)sin(radian);
            x = xcos * radius;
            y = ysin * radius;
            tx = (x/radius + 1)*0.5;
            ty = (y/radius + 1)*0.5;

            glTexCoord2f(tx, ty);
            glVertex2f(x, y);           
        }

        glEnd();
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

However when I do it I end up with a weird overlapping image effect. As shown here:[image] The original texture image is [image] however the corners are cut out and it is png format. This way of generating the texture coordinates and is took from a previous answer: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762826/texture-mapping-a-circle-made-using-gl-polygon)

Below is the code used to load the image:

```
#ifndef PNGLOAD_H

#include <png.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int png_load(const char* file_name, 
             int* width, 
             int* height, 
             char** image_data_ptr)
{
png_byte header[8];

FILE* fp = fopen(file_name, "rb");
if (fp == 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "erro: could not open PNG file %s\n", file_name);
    perror(file_name);
    return 0;
}

// read the header
fread(header, 1, 8, fp);

if (png_sig_cmp(header, 0, 8))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "error: %s is not a PNG.\n", file_name);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

png_structp png_ptr = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if (!png_ptr)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "error: png_create_read_struct returned 0.\n");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

// create png info struct
png_infop info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);
if (!info_ptr)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "error: png_create_info_struct returned 0.\n");
    png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, (png_infopp)NULL, (png_infopp)NULL);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

// create png info struct
png_infop end_info = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);
if (!end_info)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "error: png_create_info_struct returned 0.\n");
    png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr, (png_infopp) NULL);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

// the code in this if statement gets called if libpng encounters an error
if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ptr))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error from libpng\n");
    png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr, &end_info);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

// init png reading
png_init_io(png_ptr, fp);

// let libpng know you already read the first 8 bytes
png_set_sig_bytes(png_ptr, 8);

// read all the info up to the image data
png_read_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);

// variables to pass to get info
int bit_depth, color_type;
png_uint_32 temp_width, temp_height;

// get info about png
png_get_IHDR(png_ptr, info_ptr, &temp_width, &temp_height, &bit_depth, &color_type,
    NULL, NULL, NULL);

if (width) { *width = temp_width; }
if (height){ *height = temp_height; }

// Update the png info struct.
png_read_update_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);

// Row size in bytes.
int rowbytes = png_get_rowbytes(png_ptr, info_ptr);

// glTexImage2d requires rows to be 4-byte aligned
rowbytes += 3 - ((rowbytes-1) % 4);

// Allocate the image_data as a big block, to be given to opengl
png_byte* image_data;
image_data = (png_byte*)malloc(rowbytes * temp_height * sizeof(png_byte)+15);
if (image_data == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "error: could not allocate memory for PNG image data\n");
    png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr, &end_info);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

// row_pointers is for pointing to image_data for reading the png with libpng
png_bytep* row_pointers = (png_bytep*)malloc(temp_height * sizeof(png_bytep));
if (row_pointers == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "error: could not allocate memory for PNG row pointers\n");
    png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr, &end_info);
    free(image_data);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

// set the individual row_pointers to point at the correct offsets of image_data
int i;
for (i = 0; i < temp_height; i++)
{
    row_pointers[temp_height - 1 - i] = image_data + i * rowbytes;
}

// read the png into image_data through row_pointers
png_read_image(png_ptr, row_pointers);

// clean up
png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr, &end_info);

//free(image_data);
*image_data_ptr = (char*)image_data; // return data pointer

free(row_pointers);
fclose(fp);

fprintf(stderr, "\t texture image size is %d x %d\n", *width, *height);

return 1;
}

#endif
```

and:

```
unsigned int load_and_bind_texture(const char* filename)
{
char* image_buffer = NULL; // the image data
int width = 0;
int height = 0;

// read in the PNG image data into image_buffer
if (png_load(filename, &width, &height, &image_buffer)==0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read image texture from %s\n", filename);
    exit(1);
}

unsigned int tex_handle = 0;

// request one texture handle
glGenTextures(1, &tex_handle); 

// create a new texture object and bind it to tex_handle
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_handle);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 
            GL_RGB, width, height, 0,
            GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_buffer);


free(image_buffer); // free the image buffer memory

return tex_handle;
}
```

these are then called from the init() method:

```
background_texture = load_and_bind_texture("images/office-wall.png");
an_face_texture1 = load_and_bind_texture("images/clock.png");
```

Comment: You are almost certainly loading the texture incorrectly. Since you did not show us your loading code, there's no way we can help you fix the problem.

Comment: @NicolBolas the image is loaded in the same way the background is loaded. Both images are a png. I have edited the question to reflect you concerns regardless. Just incase it is of any use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the image is loaded in the same way the background is loaded.

Yes, and that is almost certainly *the problem*. While both images are PNGs, they are almost certainly not the same *format*.

Let's actually debug what you see in the loaded texture. You see 2 overlapping with 10. 3 overlapped with 9. 8 overlapped with 4. All interlaced with each other. And this pattern repeats 3 times.

It's as if you took the original image, folded it over itself vertically, and then repeated it. 3 times.

The repetition of "3" in this strongly suggests a mismatch between what libPNG actually read and what you told OpenGL the texel data actually was. You told OpenGL that the texture was in the RGB format, 3 bytes per pixel.

But not every PNG is *formatted* that way. Some PNGs are greyscale; one byte per pixel. And because you used the low-level libPNG reading interface, you read the *exact* format of the pixel data from the PNG. Yes, it decompresses it. But you're reading exactly what the PNG stored conceptually.

So if the PNG is a greyscale PNG, your call to `png_read_image` can read data that isn't 3-bytes per pixel. But you told OpenGL that the data was 3 bytes per pixel. So if the libPNG wrote 1 byte per pixel, you will be giving OpenGL the wrong texel data.

That's bad.

If you're going to use libPNG's low-level reading routines, then you *must* actually check the format of the PNG being read and adjust your OpenGL code to match.

It would be much easier to use the higher-level reading routines and explicitly telling it to translate grayscale to RGB.

Comment: Never thought about that!! However I am at a loss as to how to do it. Is there how can I convert my current png's to the correct format?

Comment: @KieranLavelle: It would be better if you made your loading code more robust, so that it could adjust to the PNG's format.

Comment: Is there any guide to go about doing this?